# Gnuplot and if contition not working with string variables

Tags: string, if-statement, gnuplot

I have a file with 7 columns like:

````
KOKEE               TIGOCONC              1.21143392716200008E-002   9999.0000000000000       1.21143404344029992E-002  1.21143392665158823E-002  1.21143392665158823E-002  
KOKEE               WESTFORD             -1.97799503925290016E-003   9999.0000000000000      -1.97799445968519991E-003 -1.97799503786376526E-003 -1.97799503786376526E-003  
SESHAN25            WETTZELL              1.39989741037330005E-002   9999.0000000000000       1.39989741037330005E-002  1.39989740975521026E-002  1.39989740975521026E-002  
WESTFORD            WETTZELL             -1.74290229035720004E-003   9999.0000000000000      -1.74290124344059997E-003 -1.74290228675636817E-003 -1.74290228675636817E-003  
KOKEE               SESHAN25             -3.83187032666899982E-003   9999.0000000000000      -3.83186908442739987E-003 -3.83187032349491209E-003 -3.83187032349491209E-003  
```

I want to plot the rest of two columns in case $1 eq KOKEE. (I have no isse when the variable is a number)
So, my command is:
````

plot [][-0.002:0.0025] 'outall.txt' u ($1 eq "KOKEE" ?($3-$7)*299792458:1/0) title "by source" w p pt 7 ps 1

```
and the system says:
internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable

         1

As far as I could see in other post, this should be fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is interpreted as floating point number.
If you want to compare column 1 as string you have to take `strcol(1)`, check `help stringcolumn`.

Your plotting command would be:

```
plot [][-0.002:0.0025] $Data u (strcol(1) eq "KOKEE" ? ...
```